# MacRuby vs MacPorts

Tags: ruby

I am beginning to learn Ruby 1.9, but unfortunately Mac ships with 1.8. I have stumbled upon 2 ways of getting Ruby 1.9.

MacRuby is Ruby 1.9 and integrates with Cocoa and Mac OSX.
The other way is installing Ruby through MacPorts.

So my question is: Which should I go for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Douglas F Shearer suggestion of RVM. I use it daily on OSX I recommend it very highly.

https://rvm.io

Importantly, it will also allow you to install different flavors of 1.9 in parallel. So you can ave the MRI implementation and the jruby implementation, and switch between them if you so desire.

Unrelated: check out homebrew for OSX. [Link](https://brew.sh/) I like it alot better than MacPorts.

Comment: If you agree, why post a second answer?

Comment: My response was to your comment which was posted on the question at the time.

Comment: Ah, I see. Concurrency issue strikes.

Comment: `rvm` all the way. If you wanna be really tricky, you can even edit your `bash` `.profile` to auto-load the proper version of Ruby every time you start it. (Highly recommended.)